# Solving a Collation Problem between Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following SQL script, trying to perform a union on two tables located on the same database. One table appears to have a different collation type

```
select * from ns.TurnsCOS 
union all 
select * from ns.TurnsValue
```

After running, I get the following error

[image]

I've read the other posts related to fixing collation issues, but adding 'Collate Latin1_General_Bin' after the from clause doesn't seem to work

How best can I resolve this collation issue between the two tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the collation of each column individually e.g.

```
select OtherCols, Col1, Col6, Col7
from ns.TurnsCOS 
union all 
select OtherCols, Col1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Col6 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Col7 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from ns.TurnsValue
```

You can permanently change the column collation as follows - but you should be very cautious doing so as it may then conflict with other existing queries:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ALTER COLUMN [Col_Name] 
            [Existing Data-Type] COLLATE [New_Collation] [NULL | NOT NULL];  
GO
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Danimov82 By altering the columns. `ALTER TABLE a ALTER COLUMN b datatype COLLATE c;`

Comment: @Danimov82 just note the changing the column collation could break any other existing access to that column.